# Leibniz rule and a heat problem with homogeneous initial and boundary data

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

**Problem**

Consider the following heat equation: $$v_{xx} = v_t , v(0,t)=0, v_x(L,t)=0, v(x,0)=0.$$ Furthermore, $I(t)$ is defined by $$I(t)=\int_0^L [v(x,t)]^2 dx.$$
Complete the following:

- Apply Leibniz rule to calculate $I'(t)$;
- Write down $I(0)$;
- Show that $I'(t)\le 0$ for all $t>0$;
- Hence, explain why there is, at most, one solution to the inhomogeneous heat equation $$v_{xx}-v_t=F(x,t), v(0,t)=0, v_x(L,t)=0, v(x,0)=g(x).$$

**Working**

$$I'(t) = {d \over dt}\int_0^L [v(x,t)]^2 dx = \int_0^L {\partial \over \partial t}[v(x,t)]^2 dx = \int_0^L 2v(x,t)v_t(x,t)dx.$$

We have that $v(x,0)=0$, so $$I(0)=\int_0^L [v(x,0)]^2 dx = 0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have done so far is correct.

For the third point:

$$I'(t) = 2 \int \limits _0 ^L v(x,t) v_t (x,t) \Bbb d x = 2 \int \limits _0 ^L v(x,t) v_{xx} (x,t) \Bbb d x = 2 \int \limits _0 ^L \frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d x} \Big( v(x,t) v_x (x,t) \Big) - v_x (x,t) ^2 \Bbb d x = 2 v(L,t) v_x (L,t) - 2 v(0,t) v_x (0,t) - 2 \int \limits _0 ^L v_x (x,t) ^2 \Bbb d x = - 2 \int \limits _0 ^L v_x (x,t) ^2 \Bbb d x \le 0 .$$

Together with $I(0) = 0$ this shows that $I(t) \le 0 \space \forall t \ge 0$. But $I(t)$ is the integral of a positive (continuous) function, so $I=0$ and then $v( \cdot , t) = 0 \space \forall t \ge 0$ i.e. $v=0$. In words: $0$ is the only solution of the homogeneous equation.

Therefore, if you have two solutions to the inhomogeneous equation, their difference must satisfy the homogeneous one; but we have just seen that $0$ is the only solution of the latter, therefore those two solutions must coincide.